Eigensystem running forever for large matrix sizes (numeric matrix)
I have a large (and numeric) square matrix and I wanna find all the eigenvalues and all eigenvectors.
Using Eigensystem command, I get the error message:
"Eigensystem::arhm: Because finding 1600 out of the 1600 eigenvalues and/or eigenvectors is likely to be faster with dense matrix methods, the sparse input matrix will be converted. If fewer eigenvalues and/or eigenvectors at machine precision would be sufficient, consider using N on the matrix and restricting this number using the second argument to Eigensystem."
I am running it for several days and it never ends.
How to find all eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a large numeric matrix?
Are there any tricks?
What is the bottleneck?

Is your matrix numeric, or are there variables?

@yarchik it is fully numeric! For around 1000x1000 matrix it is okay but at 1600x1600 matrix it runs without end - do you know what could be a fix?

If a is your matrix, it is helpful sometimes to write aa=1. * N[Normal[a]] and {vans, vecs}=Eigensystem[aa].  Does it help?

@yarchik thanks, I tried but it did not work. I checked that the eigensystem calculation works fine for matrices up to size 31x31 (961 matrix elements) but for 32x32 (1024 matrix elements) and above it runs without end. Are there any other things to try?

I guess you have to include more details in your post. I would say, MA should have no problem with matrices of the order $10^4$.

Maybe you can include 32x32 matrix in your post.

I tried Table[RandomReal[], {i, 1, 1600}, {j, 1, 1600}] // Eigensystem, and I got the result after just 1 second without any error message. Could you give a MWE?
